# SQL AND OR logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Trying to understand the AND OR logic.

I first tried the following query:

```
SELECT it.customer_id, ver.flag, it.flow 
FROM items AS it
LEFT JOIN verticals AS ver ON it.ID = ver.ID AND it.Type = ver.type
WHERE (it.flow IN (3,9) AND ver.flag = 1) OR (it.flow IN (1,2))
AND it.pDate >= DATEADD(day,-2,GETDATE())
```

I need all items where flow is 3,9 and flag is 1 or items where flow is 1,2 (regardless of flag).
The above query only gives items with 3,9.

If I change the order, I get only items that are 1,2:

```
SELECT it.customer_id, ver.flag, it.flow 
FROM items AS it
LEFT JOIN verticals AS ver ON it.ID = ver.ID AND it.Type = ver.type
WHERE (it.flow IN (1,2) OR it.flow IN (3,9) AND ver.flag = 1)
AND it.pDate >= DATEADD(day,-2,GETDATE())
```

Lastly, if I I add another pair of parenthesis on the 2 or conditions, it works. I am trying to understand why, as in the last 2 days there are all kind of items, so why there is a need to separate it from the date condition?

```
SELECT it.customer_id, ver.flag, it.flow 
FROM items AS it
LEFT JOIN verticals AS ver  ON it.ID = ver.ID AND it.Type = ver.type
WHERE ((it.flow IN (1,2) OR it.flow IN (3,9) AND ver.flag = 1))
AND it.pDate >= DATEADD(day,-2,GETDATE())
```

Comment: The easiest way to makee sure your `OR`s work with your `AND`s as you want is correctly using parenthesis (`()`); then priorities don't come into it.

Comment: Your 2 queries are exactly the same. There is no change adding extra parenthesis

Comment: @JaimeDrq except that only the last one gives correct results

Comment: If the date check applies to both branches then 3rd query should produce correct results. You claim that 2nd query is same as 1st except some swapping... in which case the second query must have had an extra closing and opening paren.

Comment: Your queries 2 and 3 *are* identical. `(it.flow IN (1,2) OR it.flow IN (3,9) AND ver.flag = 1)` is already in parentheses. Wrapping it in another lot of parentheses doesn't change anything

Comment: @DaleK, yes I am, I'm just not   always connected:) Thanks a lot for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your additional parentheses work as desired is due to the order of evaluation of AND/OR conditions. E.g. From the [OR documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/or-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> Combines two conditions. When more than one logical operator is used in a statement, **OR operators are evaluated after AND operators**. However, you can change the order of evaluation by using parentheses.

So using that information, your first condition is evaluated as follows:

```
WHERE
-- Either this condition must be true
(it.flow IN (3,9) AND ver.flag = 1)
OR
-- OR this condition must be true
(it.flow IN (1,2) AND it.pDate >= DATEADD(day,-2,GETDATE()))
```

I have added additional parentheses to clarify.

But when you add the parentheses as in your last statement it becomes:

```
WHERE
-- This condition must be true
((it.flow IN (3,9) AND ver.flag = 1) OR it.flow IN (1,2))
AND
-- AND this condition must be true
it.pDate >= DATEADD(day,-2,GETDATE())
```

Note: I have reordered the conditions so the two expressions match, and removed unnecessary parentheses to make it as clear as possible.

You may find it useful to study [Operator Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)